# No Resize Handles showing in Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

When I try to resize the Motion Tracking "Marquee", I am not getting the "Resize Handles" that used to be there yesterday. I am sure I hit a wrong key somewhere, but I dont have a clue what it might be and not sure of the name for them so google searches come back with random videos that do not mention these "Resize Handles". Any clue how to get them back?[image]

The Image on the Left is what I am getting, the Image on the Right is what SHOULD be showing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. After uninstalling, reinstalling, updating, I finally found the answer. It is the button near the Play controls, looks like a Crop Tool, says "Show/Hide Edit Mode"

[image: Show/Hide Edit Mode]